# Add a custom method to $resource in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have written a custom method to do a call to my API passing some extra parameters, but I get the following error:
TypeError test.testing is not a function.
I followed the code in here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

This is the code I use, $save for example is working fine.

I am using version 1.4.1.

```
services.factory('Calendar',function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/calendar/:id',{
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        testing: {
            method: "POST", params:{charge:true}
        }
    });
});

function( $scope, Calendar ) {

        var test = new Calendar();
        test.title = "hello";
        test.$testing();
        ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `test.$testing()`

Comment: Yes I did, it was my initial script, changed it to "testing" afterwards which is also not working.

Comment: I don't think that you've completely followed the example...

Comment: This is what I would think [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cmel8ORWHcQrMvGn3s6s?p=preview)

Comment: Thx, it works, because you have added {id: 200} but why isn't it working when I leave it out?

Comment: Because that second argument is trying to work out what goes into `:id` and it uses that object to find that value. I'll post as an answer and you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you haven't quite followed the example in the docs. See:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .factory('CreditCard', creditCard)
  .factory('Calendar', calendar);

function creditCard() {
  return $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
      {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
      charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
  });
}

function calendar() {  
  return $resource('/api/calendar/:id',
    {id: 200},
    {
      update: {
          method: 'PUT'
      },
      testing: {
          method: "POST", params:{charge:true}
      }
  });
}
```

As you can see I added that second object argument `{id:200}` that tells the `ng-resource` that in order to fill out `/api/calendar/:id` correctly it needs to pull the property `id` from that object and use its value.